# Why is my Yarn application not being transferred from Windows to the Hortoworks sandbox?

Tags: java, hadoop, spring-boot, virtualbox, hadoop-yarn

I've installed Virtalbox 5.2.12 for windows, on my Windows 7 machine, and into it
I've installed Hortonworks HDP 2.6.4 Sandbox for Virtualbox.

Then I tried my first Yarn application which I downloaded from ["Simple YARN Application"](https://spring.io/guides/gs/yarn-basic/).

This just has a java file Application.java and an application.yml resource file which I'm including for convenience below.

My first attempt of running it (after building it) was to copy the jar file manually (using SCP) into the sandbox and run it there.

For this, I modified the application.yml to have

```
hadoop:
    fsUri: hdfs://172.17.0.2:8020
    resourceManagerHost: localhost
    resource-manager-port: 8032
```

Note that I've added the "resource-manager-port: 8032" to the application.yml
to match the value in the yarn-site.xml in my sandbox.
I've also added the various aliases to my Windows hosts file.

After building the jar (gs-yarn-basic-single-0.1.0.jar) using maven (see the included pom.xml file), 
I run it in the sandbox shell using the command:

> java -jar target/gs-yarn-basic-single-0.1.0.jar

and it runs fine.

Now, I wanted to run the jar from a Windows command window, expecting the file to be transferred to the sandbox for me.
**IS that even possible?**
Assuming it is, I proceeded as follows:

I first ran the following commands in my Windows Command window and verified that some connection was made:

```
telnet localhost 8020    
telnet localhost 8032
```

I tried various application.yml, but after building and running the jar command

> java -jar target/gs-yarn-basic-single-0.1.0.jar

from the project directory they all failed.

I've tried the application.yml with the following hadoop section variations and they all failed:
1) Same as when running it in the sandbox shell

```
hadoop:
    fsUri: hdfs://172.17.0.2:8020
    resourceManagerHost: localhost
    resource-manager-port: 8032
```

Fails with:

```
[2018-05-27 19:04:29.189] boot - 31852  INFO [main] --- AbstractResourceLocalizer: About to distribute localized files
[2018-05-27 19:04:56.330] boot - 31852  INFO [main] --- Client: Retrying connect to server: 172.17.0.2/172.17.0.2:8020.
```

2) With original configuration as obtained from Git

```
hadoop:
    fsUri: hdfs://localhost:8020
    resourceManagerHost: localhost
```

Fails with:

```
[2018-05-27 19:13:11.979] boot - 29072  INFO [main] --- AbstractResourceLocalizer: About to distribute localized files
[2018-05-27 19:13:35.451] boot - 29072  INFO [Thread-7] --- DFSClient: Exception in createBlockOutputStream
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
```

3) Added the resource-manager-port as defined in the sandbox

```
hadoop:
        fsUri: hdfs://localhost:8020
        resourceManagerHost: localhost
        resource-manager-port: 8032
```

Fails with same errors as in (2)

**How can these files be distributed/localized from my Windows command window to my Sandbox running in virtualbox?**

What am i missing?

The source files are below:

Application.Java:

```
package hello;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.data.hadoop.fs.FsShell;
import org.springframework.yarn.annotation.OnContainerStart;
import org.springframework.yarn.annotation.YarnComponent;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @YarnComponent
    @Profile("container")
    public static class HelloPojo {

        private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(HelloPojo.class);

        @Autowired
        private Configuration configuration;

        @OnContainerStart
        public void onStart() throws Exception {
            log.info("Hello from HelloPojo");
            log.info("About to list from hdfs root content");

            FsShell shell = new FsShell(configuration);
            for (FileStatus s : shell.ls(false, "/")) {
                log.info(s);
            }
            shell.close();
        }

    }

}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
    hadoop:
        fsUri: hdfs://localhost:8020
        resourceManagerHost: localhost
        resource-manager-port: 8032
    yarn:
        appName: gs-yarn-basic-single
        applicationDir: /app/gs-yarn-basic-single/
        client:
            startup:
                action: submit
            localizer:
                patterns:
                  - "*.jar"
            files:
              - "file:target/gs-yarn-basic-single-0.1.0.jar"
            launchcontext:
                archiveFile: gs-yarn-basic-single-0.1.0.jar
        appmaster:
            localizer:
                patterns:
                  - "*.jar"
            containerCount: 1
            launchcontext:
                archiveFile: gs-yarn-basic-single-0.1.0.jar
                arguments:
                    --spring.profiles.active: container
```

**Information added 5-29-2018:**

If I bring up the virtualbox without starting the sandbox, then the Telnet command (in my Windows 7 command window) to localhost checking either ports 8020 or 8032 fail. After starting up the sandbox they succeed. This kinda tells me that port forwarding (from the virualbox to the sandbox) of at least these 2 ports works correctly.

the address 172.17.0.2 used in my yml is based on the output of the ifconfig command when it runs in the sandbox Shell. this address is associated with eth0.

Comment: Did you port forward the correct ports in virtualbox? `172.17.x.x` is a usually a Docker IP, not the VM IP

Comment: @cricket_007 Not sure what you mean. I see the ports 8020 and 8032 in the port forwarding of the sandbox. The address 172.17.0.2 is the ip of eth0 of the sandbox (see it when i enter ifconfig in the Shell). I will also add more comments to the bottom of my question. Would you please be more specific as to what you think I should do?